# Pathfinder explosive runes abuse

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

One of my players (a sorcerer) wants to use pathfinder's [explosive runes](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/explosiveRunes.html) as an offensive spell.

He wants to scribe runes on a book, throw it somewhere and then have a party member (a paladin with a poor casting level) cast dispel magic on it at range. He will fail and so the runes should trigger, damaging nearby enemies.

The part of rules he refers to is

> Another creature can remove them with a successful dispel magic or
>   erase spell, but attempting to dispel or erase the explosive runes and
>   failing to do so triggers the explosion.

I don't like this in the least bit but I am not sure how can I argue that it won't work.

Comment: can you detail out what exactly the problem is you are having with the method? (that will make it easier to find a flaw in that tactic as I guess you want to find downsides or how to render it inefective....on that you should really clarify the question a bit more ... thus what exactly it is you want out of an answer)

Comment: Also @Nick - I edited the question to reflect the comments, as well as linking to the spell and reorganizing to make it a little easier to read.  If any of this is wrong, please go ahead and edit the question.

Comment: Yes, why is this a problem for you? What goal are you trying to achieve by preventing it?

Answer (score 4):

[Dispel Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) is a Paladin 3 spell, what level are we talking about here? If this is low level, they are wasting a really strong spell simply to replicate the effects of a [Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball).

As for [Erase](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/erase), it is a Wizard/Sorcerer 1 or Bard 1 spell, and not (normally) available to paladins. Even if he has access to it, they are (again), wasting two spells to replicate the effects of another spell of same level (sorcerer/wizard 3).

Also, note that this is not automatic failure:

> **Erase**
>   Magic writing must be touched to be erased, and you also must succeed on a caster level check (1d20 + caster level) against **DC 15**. A natural 1 is always a failure on this check. If you fail to erase explosive runes, a glyph of warding, or a sepia snake sigil, you accidentally activate that writing instead.

So, even if this paladin is a bard 1 or wizard/sorcerer 1, meaning that he has **caster level** 1, he still has a relatively high chance of success here (about 30%, or 14 and up on a d20).

If this is a **Dispel Magic**, this scenario isn't much different, as the paladin must be at least 10th level, and thus a caster level of 7 against a DC of 11+CL of this sorcerer. If we assume they are both 10th level, then it's 1d20+7 vs DC 21 (or 30% chance of success).

Couldn't this Sorcerer simply learn **Fireball** and achieve the same result?

Comment: It doesn't even replicate fireball though as explosive rune is 6d6 and only a 10 foot radius where a fireball is up to 10d6 and 20 foot radius. The potential cheese I see is that explosive rune is permanent until discharged, so you could put a hundred explosive runes on something, toss it over, do an area greater dispel magic, and watch the fireworks. My limitation for the spell would just be that he could only have a certain number of runes at a given time. Perhaps 1/2 his caster level?

Comment: If your PCs have infinite time to prepare hundreds of explosive runes you have bigger problems, like not having a plot for your campaign.

Comment: Your nuke book is ruined as soon as the first spell is dispelled.

Comment: You dont pause a spell effect so another can happen. As soon as you cast dispel magic or erase, the dispelled explosive runes is discharged, explodes, and will cause 6d6 fire damage to your book, most likely destroying the rest of the book before dispel magic has the chance to dispel the other runes.

Comment: If you don't pause a spell effect, then you don't pause dispel magic either. So it triggers all of the runes before any explosions happen.

Comment: What i meant is that once a rune effect is triggered, you cannot stop halfway through it's effect so you can dispel another rune, the first exception must be solved before what triggered it can continue.